# How to copy config files as part of packaging for use in deployment?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I use sbt 0.13.5 to build a project with a few config files meant to be human-edited after deployment.

Using [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)'s `stage` command builds my basic output directory structure for deployment. This results in a `bin` folder with a start script and all my jars in a `lib` folder. Great.

That just leaves the text config files that should be copied into a `conf` folder verbatim alonside the `bin/` and `lib/` folders (*not included in any jar*).

How can I copy these configuration files to the output directory on the filesystem (not into any jars) using sbt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Universal convention is to copy files/directories under src/univeral/. So, to include a conf/ directory in the distribution, just add src/universal/conf and copy configuration files there. Credit: [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/ND_SNVXi9zo)

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure about an out-of-the-box support for `src/main/conf` directory or similar, and unless you find it, use the following as a workaround:

```
packageArchetype.java_application

mappings in Universal ++= {
  ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "conf" * "*").get.map { f => 
    f -> s"conf/${f.name}"
  }
}
```

It maps files under `src/main/conf` to `conf` directory in the package.

NB: I'm pretty sure I've seen *somewhere* in [the code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) support for the `conf` directory.

Comment: Interesting my hack last night was similar:
`mappings in Universal ++=  PathFinder(baseDirectory(_ / "conf"  ).value).***.pair { x => Option(x.name) }`
I still expected a file copy task to be a built in task. This approach we're taking is just adjusting a setting that happens to include files that are copied _internally_ by sbt.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a 'better' answer, as I am using sbt together with sbt-native-packager plugin:

```
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf(  baseDirectory.value / "conf" )
```

This takes all the files under the specified "conf" folder and dumps them in the package root folder.

Which uses the **MappingsHelper** I stumbled upon in the [very terse documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/universal.html#mappingshelper) for it in the sbt-native-packager.

Comment: Khoa's answer is even better, _assuming_ convention over configuration is a good thing.